# Is the Z (Zulu) required for an xsd:date?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

Regarding the xsd:date, is the Z required or implied for an xsd:date datatype?

For example, are both 2001-06-03 and 2001-06-03Z valid and are both assumed to be UTC format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[-]CCYY-MM-DD[Z|(+|-)hh:mm] is the xsd:date value space. As you can see the time zone etc are optional.

If Z is present then only it is considered UTC. If you doesn't specify Z then it is considered undetermined.

[Read this](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77041.html) and [this](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_date.html) for more details. Below are examples with comments taken from link 2.

```
2004-04-12          April 12, 2004
-0045-01-01         January 1, 45 BC
12004-04-12         April 12, 12004
2004-04-12-05:00    April 12, 2004, US Eastern Standard Time, which is 5 hours behind  
                        Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
2004-04-12Z         April 12, 2004, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
```